# How to delete a Realm child object correctly?

Tags: swift, realm

Couldn't find specific info about this in the doc or Google, so here is the example:

```
class Parent: Object {
  let children = List<Child>()
}

class Child: Object {
  weak var parent: Parent?
}
```

When I want to delete a specific Child "child1", should I just use:

```
Realm().write { realm.delete(child1) }
```

Or should I manually delete it in the parent like (cumbersome):

```
if let parent = child1.parent {
  if let idx = parent.children.indexOf(child1) {
    parent.children.removeAtIndex(idx)
  }
}
Realm().write { realm.delete(child1) }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you actually tried what `Realm().write { realm.delete(child1) }` results in? Try it and see if the `Parent` object still has the object you deleted. That will give you the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Michal - I'm in the process of converting my app's CoreData stuff into Realm, and it'll take some time before my app can build again, so I'm asking here to try to get the definitive answer before able to try it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tested it myself to be sure; simply calling:

```
Realm().write { realm.delete(child1) }
```

will automatically remove it from the list. You don't need to go in and manually delete the object from the list yourself. :)